# Vermeiden von Anredeformen

Tags: salutation, politeness, terminology

Wenn ich mit Leuten zu tun habe, bei denen ich mir nicht sicher bin, ob ich sie duzen oder lieber siezen sollte, verfalle ich gerne (und oft automatisch) in einen Satzbau, der keine Anredeform benötigt.

Oft hilft dabei ein passiver Satzbau, oft auch einfach das Nennen von Fakten, manchmal ganz anderes:

Aus "*Wie meinen Sie das?*" wird "*Wie ist das gemeint?*" oder "*Das verstehe ich nicht.*",
aus "*Wie geht's Ihnen?*" wird "*Na, alles gut?*".

Gibt es eine Bezeichnung für diese Art der Gesprächsführung?

Comment: Keine Ahnung wie man's nennt, aber im Zweifelsfalle Siezt man halt :-)

Comment: Aus "Wie geht's Ihnen?" am besten kein informelles "Na, alles gut?" machen. Das ist ja fast noch schlimmer, als zu duzen.

Comment: @Em1 Je nach Umfeld eben. Es gibt durchaus Leute, mit denen derbe Witze ausgetauscht werden können, ohne dass jemals ein Du angeboten wurde. Als förmlichere Alternative biete ich "Geht's gut?"

Comment: Bezeichnung: rumeiern

Comment: Ich mache das oft wenn ich den Namen von jemand nicht weiß :D

Comment: Btw: In Österreich ist mir aufgefallen, dass hier auch oft Sie und Du gleichzeitig verwendet werden: eigentlich siezt man sich, aber wenn es unpersönlich wird, also wenn nicht direkt der Angesprochene gemeint ist, dann kommt auf einmal das Du vor. Gibt's vielleicht auch in De, mir ist das halt nach meinen Umzug nach Ö erst hier aufgefallen.

Comment: @robsch: Meinst du als Synonym für "man"? In dem Fall ist ja aber gerade nicht mehr wirklich der Gesprächspartner gemeint, somit kann man nicht so recht von gleichzeitiger Verwendung von Sie und Du sprechen (?)

Comment: @divby0: Das ist aber nicht so eine generell anwendbare Lösung. Denn immer dann, wenn man selber gar nicht auf das Sie bestehen würde (bzw. einem ein Du sogar lieber wäre), ist es geradezu kontraproduktiv selber zu Siezen, denn damit verschreckt man den ggf. durchaus Du-willigen Gesprächspartner (der nicht selten selber nicht mehr so ganz sicher ist, ob man nun beim Sie oder beim Du war).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ja, kann man so sagen. Weil dieses `Du` zwar `Du` meint, aber doch irgendwie unpersönlich ist. Gefühlt ist es ein `man`. Aber es ist schon das Wort, nicht ein beliebiger Laut.

Answer (score 3):

**Nein.**
Zumindest gibt es dafür keine offizielle Bezeichnung, die man in einem Lehrbuch der deutschen Sprache nachschlagen könnte.

User unknown hat aber in einem Kommentar eine umgangssprachliche Antwort vorgeschlagen, der ich durchaus zustimmen würde:

> rumeiern

Das Wort ist ein Kompositum bestehend aus "rum" und "eiern". Der erste Teil "rum" ist wiederum eine Verkürzung von "herum".

Die Vorsilbe "herum" bedeutet hier, dass etwas dilettantisch und planlos gemacht wird. "Herumdoktern", "herumgurken" und "herumfuhrwerken" sind Beispiele für diese Art des Gebrauchs von "herum~".

"Eiern" bedeutet ursprünglich "rollen wie ein Ei", also ungleichmäßig und in häufig wechselnde und schwer vorhersagbare Richtungen rollen.

Das Kompositum "herumeiern" (oder "rumeiern" – "Ich eiere rum") bedeutet also, dass man ausweichende Formulierungen verwendet, ohne sich klar auf etwas festzulegen.

"herumeiern" im Duden: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herumeiern

Comment: Eine etwas vornehmere Alternative zu _rumeiern_ wäre _lavieren_.

Comment: Alternativ auch herumdrucksen. Herumdrucksen = immer wieder zögernd und nicht direkt etwas aussprechen, sich zu etwas äußern. [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herumdrucksen)

Comment: Es mag keine offizielle Bezeichnung geben, aber wischiwaschi-rumeiern hat nur zufällig Überschneidungen mit dem Thema

Comment: Ist "rumeiern" nicht meist das, was *der Gesprächspartner* tut, wodurch die Verwirrung, ob man nun beim Du oder beim Sie ist, gerade erst ausgelöst wird? Ich kenne die Situation, in der man nicht genau weiß, ob Du oder Sie bevorzugt wird, zur Genüge. Dabei sehe ich jedoch keinen Grund, mir vorwerfen zu lassen, an der Stelle "dilettantisch und planlos" vorzugehen oder etwas "in häufig wechselnde und schwer vorhersagbare Richtungen" zu tun. Ich habe i.A. durchaus eine sehr klare Vorstellung, nur bin ich oft nicht in der passenden (hierarchischen, sozialen ...) Position, diese selber vorzugeben.