# Wie nennt man es, wenn man auf „Sie“, „Du“ und „man“ in Erklärungen verzichtet?

Tags: single-word-request

Beispiel mit Sie, du, man:

> - Um das Menü zu öffnen, klicken Sie auf diese Schaltfläche.
> - Um das Menü zu öffnen, klicke auf diese Schaltfläche.
> - Um das Menü zu öffnen, klickt man auf diese Schaltfläche.

oder ohne:

> - Das Menü kann geöffnet werden, indem diese Schaltfläche angeklickt wird.

Wie nennt man diese Ausdrucksweise?

Hintergrund: Ich erstelle gerade eine Anleitung und will sie möglichst formell und unpersönlich klingen lassen. Wenn ich aber jemanden diesen Stil erklären wollte, dann wüsste ich dafür keinen Begriff.

Comment: Alternativ: [Nominalstil](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalstil), z.B. "Das Öffnen des Menüs erfolgt durch das Anklicken der Schaltfläche."

Comment: Oder auch "Zum Öffnen des Menüs auf die Schaltfläche klicken"

Comment: Von Passiv-Formulierungen wird in Anleitungen zum verständlichen Schreiben eher abgeraten (siehe diesen Satz).

Comment: Das nennt man zwanghaft. ;)

Comment: Verwandt, aber kein Duplikat: [Vermeiden von Anredeformen](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/8368/2594)

Answer (score 8):

So eine Schreibweise nutzt vorwiegend Verben im Passiv, daher [Passivstil](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Passivstil).

Answer (score 6):

Wenn es nur um die Vermeidung von persönlicher Anrede geht, kann man es wohl schlicht einen "Stil ohne persönliche Anrede" nennen.

In dem Beispiel wird eine Passivkonstruktion eingesetzt. Passivsätze haben zwar kein grammatikalisches Subjekt, aber man kann einen Handlungsträger mit Hilfe von Formulierungen wie "von Ihnen / durch Sie" usw. einbauen (als Präposition). Das Passiv ist also nicht an sich anredelos.

Das Passiv wird u.a. zur generalisierenden Beschreibung von Sachverhalten,  also Prinzipien oder Normen, eingesetzt. So auch in dem Beispielsatz *"Das Menü kann geöffnet werden, indem diese Schaltfläche angeklickt wird."* Aber als durchgängiger Stil in praktischen Anleitungen mit mehrstufigen Abläufen wäre das unangemessen, weil beim Lesen erst eine Interpretation erfolgen und eine Handlungsentscheidung getroffen werden müsste. Es kann sehr wohl stellenweise für Hintergrundinformationen zum Verständnis oder für Hinweise auf alternative Möglichkeiten sinnvoll sein. Bei dieser Textart sollte man das nicht als "förmlicheren" Stil missverstehen, denn es wirkt hier überhaupt nicht so.

#### Infinitivkonstruktion für direkte Anweisungen ohne Anrede

Um Anleitungen und Aufforderungen kurz und knapp zu halten, ist eine  **Ersatzform des Imperativs** üblich, die grammatikalisch eine **Infinitivkonstruktion** ist (keine persönliche Anrede, das Verb wird nicht flektiert):

> - Zum Öffnen des Menüs diese Schaltfläche *klicken*.
> - *Um* das Menü *zu öffnen*, bitte diese Schaltfläche *klicken*.
> - Menü *schließen.*

Siehe auch diese Frage: [Woher stammt die Verwendung des Infinitivs als Ersatz für den Imperativ?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4874/woher-stammt-die-verwendung-des-infinitivs-als-ersatz-f%C3%BCr-den-imperativ)

Answer (score 0):

Man kann dies als *unpersönlich* bezeichnen.

Comment: Ja, eigentlich schon. Aber 'man' ist wohl auch unpersönlich, vermute ich.

Comment: Genau. Zum Spaß habe ich es so geschrieben.